# JQUERY : Underline DIV text when string is found (Multiple Strings)

Tags: jquery

I need to highlight multiple strings within a DIV.  This is my current script, set to gets underlined, but changed from does not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("div:contains('set to')").each(function()
{
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.html( $el.html().replace(/set to/g, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">SET</span> to') );
});


$("div:contains('changed from')").each(function()
{
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.html( $el.html().replace(/changed from/g, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">changed from</span>') );
});

</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me (https://jsfiddle.net/n3o38hmf/1/), do you have any errors in your console, are you running that script on document ready or at the end of the body?

Comment: Not sure, just updated (jsfiddle.net/n3o38hmf/1) weird output

Comment: You don't need the script tags in the fiddle - they are already included.  Can you paste your entire pages code into the html window in the fiddle, press save and then  copy the new link (above you copied the old one)